# How similar are the KJV and the Reina Valera bibles?

Tags: bible, bible-translation, kjv

I know that the two books are similar to each other in that they’re both very influential printed bibles, and that they’re used by the same or similar denominations of Christianity. And that both contain what are now archaic forms of English and Spanish (unless you choose more modern editions that use more modern language).

However, how similar are the contents of the two bibles? In terms of if I look at an individual sentence, will the contents be much the same. (I’m an English speaker learning Spanish)

Comment: The two translations are both based on the Hebrew Masoretic Text, regarding the Old Testament scriptures and both are based on the Textus Receptus regarding the New Testament scriptures, see [Wikipedia - Reina Valera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reina-Valera). I cannot comment on the quality of the translation into Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging on the subject - there is quite a lot of information to be had, but no direct comparisons between KJV and RVR.

For example,

- https://www.apbrown2.net/web/TranslationComparisonChart.htm

offers translation comparison statistics, and compares Biblical passages across different Bible versions. As these already have slightly different interpetations in English, I imagine that it is unlikely that any cross-language translation will have much significant impact.

Here is a whole magazine dedicated to the subject of Bible translation:

- http://www.ubs-translations.org/bt/

And this site contains the text for the most popular translations:

- https://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-versions/

with the [KJV](https://www.biblestudytools.com/kjv/) and [RVR](https://www.biblestudytools.com/rvr/).

Answer (score 1):

The bilingual Robert Breaker of the cloud church has a lot of material on this topic. You might find some info in his writings:

- http://www.rrb3.com/mypub/books/my_books_menu.htm

His view appears to be that there are things he cannot preach in Spanish without a corrected RVR. Such a bible exists however and is called the Valera 1602 purified, or La Valera 1602 Purificada.

In particular here is a chart comparing versions:

- http://www.rrb3.com/bibles/spnbibl/my_comparison_of_spanish_bibles.htm